# Generating dataset for LFSR stream cipher

Tags: algorithm-design, lfsr

I have implemeneted the code for cryptanalysis of LFSR stream cipher . But I have a problem with generation of dataset i.e to get valid  pairs using LFSR stream cipher. In the stinson book it is mentioned that if coefficients $$(c0,c1,\dots,cm-1)$$ are chosen in **suitable** way and if **non-zero** $$k=(k1,\dots,km)$$ is chosen then we will get a periodic stream cipher with period $2^{m-1}$.

What should be the values of $$c0,c1,\dots,cm-1$$ that I should choose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly using an LFSR output as a keystream generator is insecure, due to the Berlekamp-Massey attack which only needs $2m$ bits of known or guessed plaintext to break the stream with period $2^m-1.$

The coefficients  you are asking about, must define a polynomial $$c(x)=c_0+c_1 x +c_{m-1} x^{m-1}+x^m$$ with $c_0=1,$ and $c(x)$ must be primitive. See Wikipedia [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear-feedback_shift_register).

Comment: I am actually implementing the Berlekamp-Massey attack .. for that I needed a dataset to check my code i.e I need valid (input,output) streams . So I am running some LFSR's to encrypt some PT's . Thanks for the answer anyways